# Facebook's Flow type for a nested object with ids

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I couldn't find in the [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/) how to make a type for a nested object with 
ids such as:

```
const form = {
    title: string,
    fields: {
        f1: {
            id: string,
            title: string
            ...
        },
        f2: {
            id: string,
            title: string
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

If the property "fields" was an array I would do something like:

```
type form = {
    title: string,
    fields: Array<Field>
}
```

So I am looking for something like:

```
type form = {
    title: string,
    fields: ObjectOf<string: Field>
}
```

The last code blocks's syntax is of course false and is used to illustrate what I'm aiming for. How can I describe a nested object with ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you need:

```
/* @flow */

type Field = {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

type Fields = {
  [key: string]: Field
}

type Form = {
    title: string,
    fields: Fields,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [Objects as maps](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)?

That would be

```
type Form = {
  title: string,
  fields: {[string]: Field}
}
```

Hope it helps!